# How to apply function to newly added rows in php

Tags: javascript, php

i want to populate the select drop down(from database) based on the other select(which i am fetching from Database). i am able to achieve this dependency but only for first row.
After adding a new row, my code with dependency is not working which is because i need to pass the row id .
Kindly advise how can i pass the row id to the newly added row in html table.

html:

```
<select name="category[]" id="categoriesSelect[]"  onchange ="loadareaa(this)">
                <option value="">Select category</option>
    </select>
```

function1:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                alert(newcell.childNodes[0].type);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;
                    case "checkbox":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                                case "select":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = count;
                            //newcell.childNodes[0].id = count;
                            break;
                            break;
                    case "select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = count;
                            //newcell.childNodes[0].id = count;
                            break;
                }

            }
        }
```

function2:

```
function loadareaa(x) {
     var catid = x.value;
     var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
     var rowCount = table.rows.length;
     var subcat = document.getElementById("subcatsSelect[]");
        subcat.options.length = 0;
        for(var k = 0; k < rowCount; k++) { 
        for(var i = 0; i < subcats[catid].length; i++) {
                subcat.options[i] = new Option(subcats[catid][i].val,subcats[catid][i].id)
      
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure brackets are allowed in ID attributes? `subcatsSelect[]`

Comment: @MarkusZeller HTML5 has lifted nearly all restrictions on valid ID values, it basically boils down to _“must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any ASCII whitespace”_ (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) Whether they can be used within selectors without any problems or need for additional masking, is a different question though.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly is not working here, and what exactly you want to add which row ID to?

Comment: i could fix the issue by looping through.